# Is there a way to transition from one screen to another, without using any events, just using time alone?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Say I have two pages :-

Tester1.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gelijk_spel/Testers2.dart';

class Testers1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: IconButton(
              icon: Hero(
                  tag: 'elderimg',
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/Images/elder.png', width: 100, height: 100,),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => Testers2()
                    )
                );
              }
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

and Tester2.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Testers2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Screen2'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Placeholder0'),
            Hero(
              tag: 'elderimg',
              child: Image.asset('assets/Images/elder.png',width: 100, height: 100,)
            ),
            Text('Placeholder1'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

I want to be able to transition from Tester1 to Tester2, but instead of having to click on the screen or any events, just sequentially, after some time. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is to use `Timer` and a `StatefulWidget` so you can set up a timer with a trigger that will run your Navigation code as soon as the timer runs out and triggers.

This is the code example:

```dart
class Testers1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Testers1State createState() => _Testers1State();
}

class _Testers1State extends State<Testers1> {


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container()
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Testers2()));
    });
  }
}
```

```dart
class Testers2 extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Screen2'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Placeholder0'),
            Text('Placeholder1'),
          ],
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

NOTE: `Timer` is coming from the `'dart:async'`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use Future.delayed() on init() function in first page

Like this(Add this to First page):

```
  Future<void> initState()  {
    super.initState();

//replace 1000 with your time required
  Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
           Navigator.push(currentContext,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Testers2()));
        },
      });
}
```

Comment: I don't have an `init()`  function in my first page, so it cannot find `super.initState()` either. Also the `currentContext` is not found.
My apologies, I am still new to Flutter